# I'm recieving different data when I make API request even though the parameters are right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

So I created an API request on my NodeJS code and what I supposed to get is like this

```
    [
        {
            "weight": {
                "imperial": "7  -  10",
                "metric": "3 - 5"
            },
            "id": "abys",
            "name": "Abyssinian",
            "cfa_url": "http://cfa.org/Breeds/BreedsAB/Abyssinian.aspx",
            "vetstreet_url": "http://www.vetstreet.com/cats/abyssinian",
            "vcahospitals_url": "https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/cat-breeds/abyssinian",
            "temperament": "Active, Energetic, Independent, Intelligent, Gentle",
            "origin": "Egypt",
            "country_codes": "EG",
            "country_code": "EG",
            "description": "The Abyssinian is easy to care for, and a joy to have in your home. They’re affectionate cats and love both people and other animals.",
            "life_span": "14 - 15",
            "indoor": 0,
            "lap": 1,
            "alt_names": "",
            "adaptability": 5,
            "affection_level": 5,
            "child_friendly": 3,
            "dog_friendly": 4,
            "energy_level": 5,
            "grooming": 1,
            "health_issues": 2,
            "intelligence": 5,
            "shedding_level": 2,
            "social_needs": 5,
            "stranger_friendly": 5,
            "vocalisation": 1,
            "experimental": 0,
            "hairless": 0,
            "natural": 1,
            "rare": 0,
            "rex": 0,
            "suppressed_tail": 0,
            "short_legs": 0,
            "wikipedia_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyssinian_(cat)",
            "hypoallergenic": 0,
            "reference_image_id": "0XYvRd7oD",
            "image": {
                "id": "0XYvRd7oD",
                "width": 1204,
                "height": 1445,
                "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/0XYvRd7oD.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
```

But what I received is this

```
`[
    {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            97,
            110,
            100,
            32,
            108,
            111,
            118,
            101,
            32,
            98,
            111,
            116,
            104,
            32,
            112,
            101,
            111,
            112,
            108,
        ]
    },
  
    {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            101,
            100,
            95,
            116,
            97,
            105,
            108,
            34,
            58,
            48,
            44,
            34,
            115,
            104,
            111,
            114,
            116,
            95
        ]
    }
]`
```

and here's my code

```
`    app.get("/cat-list", (req, res) => {

        const link = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds?limit=10&page=0&" + process.env.API_KEY;

        https.get(link, resp => {
        const data = [];

        resp.on('data', chunk => {
         data.push(chunk);
        });

        resp.on('end', () => {
         res.send(data)
        });
     }).on('error', err => {
      console.log('Error: ', err.message);
   });

})`
```

I tried to change data variable `let data = ""`  and just increment it like this `data += chunk` but It doesn't look like it returns json because POSTMAN returns the data but it's like this
[image: POSTMAN result]
and when I received it on the front end on Firefox it says XML Parsing Error: syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTTPS` or `HTTP`, module’s functionality is fairly low-level.
The callback function(`data`) to be executed as soon as all of the data is received. You also need to parse the response data manually as handling string append.

This code will works

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const configuration = {
    apiKey: '***************************************',
};

// Set up the server
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

// Set up the ChatGPT endpoint
app.get("/cat-list", async (req, res) => {
    https.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds?' + configuration.apiKey, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been received.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            res.send(JSON.parse(data))
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
});

// Start the server
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Open URL

```
http://localhost:8080/cat-list
```

Result

[image]